# putting results from mysql to same row

Tags: php, mysql

I have this one mysql table  with several columns.
Using php I would like to show the results in a html table.
so far so good, but I would like to show the name_of_insurance and the amount in one row but in different colums depending on the month_of_payment.

mysql/php code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Monatsübersicht</title>
<link href="design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<?php
include 'connect.php';
// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT name_of_insurance, amount, month_of_payment FROM insurance     where active = 'on'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>März</th><th>Apr</th><th>Mai</th><th>Jun</th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Okt</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dez</th></tr>";
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name_of_insurance"]. "</td><td>" .     $row["amount"]. "</td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";    
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($link);

?>

</html>
```

how can I put the results to diferent columns withut having more than one query or $result?

Thanks in advance.
BR
Florian

Comment: What is the format of value in `row['month_of_payment']`?

Comment: Hi u_mulder,the format is varchar and the content of the column is jan.feb.mar, ... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the fact that *month_of_payment* column values are in `Jan, Feb, März` etc. format, **the solution** to your problem would be like this:

Create a month array comprising of all the possible month values from *month_of_payment* column, like this:

```
$monthArr = array('Jan', 'Feb', 'März', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez');
```

Now in each iteration of `while` loop, create a `for` loop to check which month `$row["month_of_payment"]` value falls into and display it in the appropriate table cell, like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name_of_insurance"]. "</td>";
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i){
        echo "<td>";
        if($row["month_of_payment"] == $monthArr[$i]){
            echo $row["amount"];
        }
        echo "</td>";
    } 
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Where `$count` is number of elements/months in `$monthArr` array i.e. `$count = count($monthArr);`

Here's **the complete code**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Monatsübersicht</title>
    <link href="design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql = "SELECT name_of_insurance, amount, month_of_payment FROM insurance where active = 'on'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $monthArr = array('Jan', 'Feb', 'März', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez');
    $count = count($monthArr);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>März</th><th>Apr</th><th>Mai</th><th>Jun</th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Okt</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dez</th></tr>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name_of_insurance"]. "</td>";
            for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i){
                echo "<td>";
                if($row["month_of_payment"] == $monthArr[$i]){
                    echo $row["amount"];
                }
                echo "</td>";
            } 
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";    
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Rajdeep Paul,
thanks man... This was very helpful. It solved my problem!
Your assumption reg. the month_of_payment wasn´t incorrect but it needed a bit of correction. ;-)
But at the end, it was very helpful!
Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rajdeep Paul:
The correct answer to my question is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Monatsübersicht</title>
<link href="design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'connect.php';
// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT name_of_insurance, amount, month_of_payment FROM insurance where active = 'on'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$monthArr = array('jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec');
$count = count($monthArr);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>März</th><th>Apr</th><th>Mai</th><th>Jun</th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Okt</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dez</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name_of_insurance"]. "</td>";
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i){
            echo "<td>";
            if($row["month_of_payment"] == $monthArr[$i]){
                echo $row["amount"];
            }
            echo "</td>";
        } 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";    
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
</body>
</html>
```